# Serialze datatable but nest the JSON

Tags: json, vb.net

I am using VB.Net and would like to serialize results from a table in my database.  I would like to nest the JSON to reduce the amount of data in the string.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I found this code

```
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select Town, Name From Personell", cn)

                con.Open()
                Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                da.Fill(dt)
                Dim serializer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
                Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))()
                Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
                For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
                    row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
                    For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr(col))
                    Next
                    rows.Add(row)
                Next
                Dim X = serializer.Serialize(rows)
                Return 'serializer.Serialize(rows)
            End Using
```

This gives me

```
[{"Town":"Wimbledon","Name":"Paul"},{"Town":"Luton","Name":"Sam"},{"Town":"Wimbledon","Name":"Sue"}]..
```

What I would like is to get this and potentially have another nest if that's possible:

```
 [{"Town":"Wimbledon", [{"Name":"Paul"},{"Name":"Sam"},{"Name":"Sue"}]]..
```

Many thanks,

Derek.

Comment: please post code you've tried as well as structure of the data in the table. otherwise, we can't really help.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy..  I did that then deleted..  doh..  I will post again shortly..  :)

Comment: I'd create a new object that has the JSON structure that you are after, such as as town class with a List(Of People) as a member. Write a routine populate this object, then serialize the object to JSON, and you will have something close to what you are after.

Comment: ` reduce the amount of data in the string` is not a good reason to change the structure - databases are all about relationships and changing that might make the data unusable or wrong.  Case in point, "Sam" is not from Wimbledon.

Comment: Thank you too Plutonix..  I did make a little mistake in my sample there, well spotted..  My client wants to have as little data travelling between database and an app.  Would you suggest to just have a non nested structure, knowing that it may change?